# I am trying to get the ear file from WAS8.5 to register on Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay

Good day,

Can someone help me please,

I am using WAS 8.5 to deploy ear files, once the ear file is deployed, I am not able to register the ear file on Liferay,

Did anyone experience this issues before,

Please advice.

Comment: Do you get any exception? Or do you mean that the portlet .ear is deployed ok (in terms of WAS), but the portlet is not registered in Liferay?

Comment: Hi Mark, I do not get an exception the portlet is deployed correctly on WAS , but they do not register in Liferay .

Comment: See my answer. Your portlet probably didn't go through LR auto deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

Your portlet .war file probably didn't go through Liferay auto deploy process. Before the portlet is deployed to WebSphere, Liferay needs to manipulate the .war file and add its custom configuration and libraries. Without the auto deployment, the application is invisible to Liferay.

Does the portlet .war contain `util-java.jar` library (+ `util-bridges.jar`, + `util-taglib.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder)? If not, it was not auto deployed.

The auto deployment is configured using these properties in `portal-ext.properties` file.

```
#
# Set this to true to enable auto deploy of layout templates, portlets, and
# themes.
#
auto.deploy.enabled=true

#
# Set the directory to scan for layout templates, portlets, and themes to
# auto deploy.
#
auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${liferay.home}/deploy

#
# Set the directory where auto deployed WARs are copied to. The application
# server or servlet container must know to listen on that directory.
# Different containers have different hot deploy paths. For example, Tomcat
# listens on "${catalina.base}/webapps" whereas JBoss listens on
# "${jboss.home.dir}/deploy". Set a blank directory to automatically use the
# application server specific directory.
#
auto.deploy.websphere.dest.dir=${env.USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/wsadmin-deploy
```

Plus other configuration options.

What you need to do:

1. Copy the .war file into `auto.deploy.deploy.dir`.
2. Take the modifed .war file from `auto.deploy.websphere.dest.dir`.
3. Now you can deploy the modified .war to WebSphere application server.

**If you build with Maven...**

If you build with Maven, you can automate the auto deployment with the help of [liferay-maven-plugin](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en).

Sample configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.10.11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-deploy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>direct-deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appServerDeployDir><<LR will save the modified .war to this folder>></appServerDeployDir>
                <appServerType>websphere</appServerType>
                <liferayVersion>6.2.10.11</liferayVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The plugin executes Liferay and can be further configured through `src/main/resources/portal-ext.properties` file.

My common configuration:

```
auto.deploy.copy.commons.logging = false
auto.deploy.copy.log4j = false
auto.deploy.websphere.wsadmin.app.manager.query =
```

Comment: Hi Thomas , the settings posted here already exist and they working fine , without issues , what is happening currently is that , i am deploying ears files  directly to WAS and they deploy without issues , what i need is to have the ear file deploy to WAS and also register on Liferay automatically

Comment: Does the portlet .war contain `util-java.jar` library (in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder)? If not, it was not auto deployed.

Comment: Yes the util-java.jar is there ,

Comment: or maybe i should ask it this way , can an ear file be deployed to Liferay ??

Comment: Good. Now we really need Liferay log. Try to find message `Deploying <<your portlet>> from queue`. Can you find the message and any following exception? Does Liferya log other deployment attempts?

Comment: Regarding .ear vs .war - When discussing Liferay auto deployment, you work with .war files. When discussing WebSphere deployment, you work with .ear wrapping the auto deployed .war file. You create .ear file, because you want to give WebSphere more information than that's contained in the .war. It makes no difference regarding Liferay deployment.

Comment: as per previos post : i found this ,[11/11/15 9:26:16:003 SAST] 00000106 application   E   Error Rendering View[/customerUser/List.xhtml]
                                 javax.el.ELException: /customerUser/List.xhtml @26,235 value="#{jsfcrud_class['za.co.sbsa.ssa.userdetails.controller.util.JsfUtil'].jsfcrud_method['getAsConvertedString'][customerController.getLeadDP()][customerController.converter].jsfcrud_invoke}": , the stack trace it too long , cant post all of it here

Comment: It seems the exception is related to request processing (attempt to render customerUser/List view). That assumes the portlet was already deployed and placed to a page. That's confusing. What problem exactly do we deal with? Can you see the portlet in the "Add portlet to page" menu? Were you able to place it to a page?

Comment: t com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)

Comment: at javax.faces.component.UIParameter.getValue(UIParameter.java:143)
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getBehaviorParameters(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:629)
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(CommandLinkRenderer.java:230)
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(CommandLinkRenderer.java:125)

Comment: at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
 at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)Deploying <<your portlet>> from queue
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)

Comment: at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
 at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
 at com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ViewHandlerCompatImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerCompatImpl.java:52)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)

Comment: at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:227)
 at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:85)
 at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:112)
 at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
 at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)

Comment: at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
 at com.liferay.faces.bridge.GenericLiferayFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericLiferayFacesPortlet.java:43)
 at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
 at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
 at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at za.co.sbsa.ssa.userdetails.bean.CustomerUserFacade.getLeadDP(CustomerUserFacade.java:259)
 at za.co.sbsa.ssa.userdetails.controller.CustomerUserController.getLeadDP(CustomerUserController.java:421)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: My last question was - It seems the exception is related to request processing (attempt to render customerUser/List view). That assumes the portlet was already deployed and placed to a page. That's confusing. What problem exactly do we deal with? Can you see the portlet in the "Add portlet to page" menu? Were you able to place it to a page?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your help , someone from my team will help me with the issue, apparently there's an ant script from Liferay , i will update the chat as soon as i found the solution ,